# why can't I use the way of using a variable inside a quotes without using a plus sign?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to make a subpattern and to show it on the screen by using res.send, like so:

```
app.get('/r/:something', (req, res) => {
    const { something } = req.params;
    res.send('<h1>Browsing the ${something} on the screen</h1>')
})
```

Comment: You probably meant to use back-ticks instead of single quote? `\`<h1>Browsing the ${something} on the screen</h1>\``

Comment: Your quote marks (') should be backticks (`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backticks for templated strings not single quotes

```
res.send(`<h1>Browsing the ${something} on the screen</h1>`)
```

Comment: thank you! it is working now